# jquery.corner problem with IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Been making this site for the past week. Only just came across this error in IE8.

There's an error in the `jquery.corner.js` file:

```
Webpage error details
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Timestamp: Sat, 25 Sep 2010 16:13:34 UTC
Message: Unexpected call to method or property access.
Line: 163
Char: 17
Code: 0
URI: file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/User/Desktop/diverse2/js/jquery.corner.js
```

Here's a link to the site, it will view normal in chrome etc but in IE8 the error also stops other jQuery plugins from working e.g jQuery.cycle.

http://eosa.co.cc/themes2/diverse2/

Here is the rounded corner codes:

```
$("#pageTitle, #pageTitle div#title").corner("tl bl 5px");
$("#navbar, .postDetail").corner("bl br 5px");
$(".jqueryslidemenu ul li ul li a, .boxGrey, div#slideshow-container, #searchForm, #pageTitleContainer, .twoThirdsGrey, a.button, a.button-2, .rounded").corner("tl tr bl br 5px");
```

That file is located in `js/rounded.js`

and the file for `jquery.corner.js` is located in `js/jquery.corner.js`.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that in IE you can't access the append child method for certain elements like input. Basically the plugin is trying to round certain elements in a manner that IE does not like.

You have two choices:

1. Surround these elements in a div - either through jquery code or in your actual markup, and then round that wrapper div.
2. Use a different plugin. [Jquery Curvy Corners](http://code.google.com/p/jquerycurvycorners/) should work for you.

Comment: You know of anywhere I can find a tutorial in which to append a div tag around elements via jquery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/, and also take a look at a lot of these questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+wrap. If it doesn't work out you can always come back and ask for help.